# find a value in the last cell in specified column (according to its header)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bit tricky (to me) task to do. I want to create the macro which will find a value in the last cell in specified column (according to its header). So for example It will find the last value in a column called "test".

Comment: What have you tried?  Perhaps record a macro and then try editing it and then ask a question when you get stuck rather than asking for code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it tricky for you because you didn't try, or because you tried and weren't able to figure it out? It's always nice if you provide your code first so we can see what exactly you're doing and how we can help make it work.

Anyway, here's something I put together that does what you ask. It makes the assumption that we will be searching in `Sheet 1`. In the `Visual Basic Editor (VBE)`, open `Sheet1` and paste this code. You can then use it like a regular macro (be sure to change the headerrow value and search string to meet your needs).

**CODE**

```
Public Sub FindValueInColumn()

    Dim headerRow As Integer
    Dim totalColumnsInHeaderRow As Integer
    Dim searchColumn As Integer
    Dim lastRowInSearchColumn As Integer
    Dim columnSearchString As String

    headerRow = 1   'change this to correct header row
    totalColumnsInHeaderRow = Cells(headerRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    columnSearchString = "Test" 'change to the text to search
    searchColumn = 0

    'for every column that has a value in it in the header row
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    For currentColumn = 1 To totalColumnsInHeaderRow
        'if that value equals what we're looking for (in this case, "Test")
        If StrComp(Cells(headerRow, currentColumn).Value, columnSearchString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            'save the column that contains the value, then exit the loop
            searchColumn = currentColumn
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'if the column of interest exists in the header row
    If searchColumn > 0 Then
        'Set F2 equal to the last value in that column
        lastRowInSearchColumn = Cells(Rows.Count, searchColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("F2").Value = Cells(lastRowInSearchColumn, searchColumn).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Comment: Hello Sam. Always before I post any question on Stackoverflow I try to solve the problem by myself. Not everytime I am able to do this, so then I come here. Most of my qestions consisted my current code. However, I have limited knowledge of VBA, so in this particular circumstance I was not able to amend the codes which I found on the internet to be even close to the state I'd like to acheive. Anyway, your code provides the result in F2, while that is not required for me as I have this type of code. The only thing what I would need is to select the last value in the Test column.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to then post what you've tried so we can see it and guide you in the right direction where needed. Having the code output the last value into `F2` was meant as an example to show you how it works. If all you need to do is select the last cell, then you can use `Cells(lastRowInSearchColumn, searchColumn).Select` in place of `Range("F2).Value = ...`

Comment: It works perfect! I understand that a post without the code it is a bit akward but as mentioned I couldn't come up with anything valuable at that point. Thank you Sam for helping me even I put so few details. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem - Glad to help. Best of luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I truely love seeing the different coding styles. There's more than one way to skin this cat, apparently.

```
Sub Last_Cell_In_Column()
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim col As Long

   Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   col = 0
   col = sh.Rows(1).Find("test").Column
   If col > 0 Then
      MsgBox (sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Value)
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Agreed, so many ways to do one thing. +1 for picking the much shorter, simpler route ;)